# ElasticSearch 2.3 scroll api

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to test my future application work with plain requests, and it seems like docs are a little bit out of sync or my head is. Here is what [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-scroll.html) state:

```
[create scroll query, everything's ok with that]

[use your scroll]
curl -XGET  'localhost:9200/_search/scroll'  -d'
{
    "scroll" : "1m", 
    "scroll_id" : "c2Nhbjs2OzM0NDg1ODpzRlBLc0FXNlNyNm5JWUc1" 
}'
```

However, ElasticSearch tells me there is no such index as _search:

```
"error": {
    "type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
    "reason": "Invalid index name [_search], must not start with '_'",
    "index": "_search"
},
"status": 400
```

I've tried to use `/{index}/{type}/_search/scroll` URI as well, but with no luck. What am i doing wrong and how can i manually use scroll API?

Comment: Could you post the curl command that you are using - please scrub the hostname

Comment: @JVXR shame on me, i've missed that i've deleted just part of my query parameters, so actual URI was longer and incorrect. The API is working as expected.

Comment: Feel free to delete this question or post the answer with the actual failure you had. It will probably help someone!